# How to run multiple Spring Boot application sharing same context?

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot, microservices

I want to run multiple micro-services app sharing same context so that I can run my custom security filter for multiple spring boot(micro-services) app.

Example:

User services : https://ip:port/myapp/user

Product services : https://ip:port/myapp/product

Comment services : https://ip:port/myapp/comment

And I should run  a common filter(Custom Security Filter) for all micro-services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @luboskrnac suggests - for the security you could simply extract your common logic into a separate JAR.

Regarding your shared application context (I assume you are just referring to the shared URL space, rather than sharing any particular state across the apps etc), then yes - you should use something like `Zuul` - this can act as a singular interface between external and all your microservices (which, under the hood would all be running in their own unique application context namespace/port number - but `Zuul` can group those together and expose them with nice URLs on a consistent location).

Luckily the whole [Netflix microservice](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/spring-cloud-netflix.html) stack is well supported by Spring, so its reasonably straight forward to get up and running with `Zuul` and `Eureka` (the discovery service).

I have a `hello-world` setup of the stack written up here (along with the code): http://automateddeveloper.blogspot.co.uk/2015/09/spring-boot-netflix-oss-adventure-into.html

Answer (score 0):

Extract that filter into separate JAR that will be used by each microservice. That JAR will be separate project versioned and deployed into your artifact repository independently.

In fact in microservice environment, you will have much more "common" beans/functionality that should be shared across services. Therefore such common JAR is necessary in microservice environment.

Comment: Thanks @luboskrnac for your quick answer, but this is only half of the answer. Could you please help me with configuring multiple boot app with same context...

Comment: I suspect you don't understand my answer. You can't share single context across various microservices. You can have common project with Spring configuration that will be loaded into various projects as shared JAR. I hope you are familiar with shared library concept.

Comment: Can I use any gateway like Zuul to configure common context ?

Comment: I am not familiar with Zuul, but trying to do that doesn't make sense to me. You are trying to share code, not state.

Comment: So suppose for above example, lets below are the end points of microservices :

Https://ip:port/userservices/~
Https://ip:port/productservices/~
Https://ip:port/search/~

What can you recommend here to have a common context ? is it possible ? like 
Https://ip:port/myapp/userservices/~
Https://ip:port/myapp/productservices/~
Https://ip:port/myapp/search/~

Comment: Thanks @luboskrnac